# FacePy Facebook post error

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, post

I'm trying to integrate Facebook with FacePy and getting the error `FacebookError at / No exception supplied`. The request is working on the command line through curl, and actually posting on Facebook, so I know permissions and access token are correct. If I remove the graph.post line, there is no error thrown, so I reckon it must be triggered by the actual post attempt. I'm developing locally btw. I have got django-facebook working locally, so that shouldn't be a problem. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

@login_required
def index(request):
    proposed_event_list = Event.objects.all().filter(date__gt=datetime.now()).annotate(c=Count('userprofile')).filter(c__lt=4).order_by('date')
    confirmed_event_list = Event.objects.all().filter(date__gt=datetime.now()).annotate(c=Count('userprofile')).filter(c__gt=3).order_by('date')
    past_event_list = Event.objects.all().filter(date__lt=datetime.now()).order_by('date')

    graph = GraphAPI("AAAD392hkaGX0BAP0U1IZClcPh6qZCpIZBqiP5ze3ELZB14ZChropfyWT6OeELgfgYiY929Adi90kgLGXdLQ3qOQM0KsjvQ6S9Q4VbuHXwhAZD")
    graph.post(path="https://graph.facebook.com/426364711649/feed", retry=1, message="Hello")

    context = RequestContext(request)
    context['proposed_event_list'] = proposed_event_list
    context['confirmed_event_list'] = confirmed_event_list
    context['past_event_list'] = past_event_list
    return render_to_response('crewcal.html', context)
```

Error:

```
FacebookError at /
No exception supplied
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: FacebookError
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/facepy/graph_api.py in post, line 69
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages',
...
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Fri, 21 Sep 2012 18:49:11 -0500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a Facebook permissions error. Finding it tricky to get permissions right. I found this helpful to get an access token with widest permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Yeah, sorry about this. Exceptions in the 0.8 series are kinda broken in that they don't display the error message by default (you have to explicitly print Exception#message to get to it) which makes these things really hard to debug. I'll push a new version in the morning with the commit that fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

The request method should be request.POST rather than GET since you want to post to the Facebook Graph.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. I get the same error when I create a dedicated view coming from a form giving rise to a POST request method. Anyway, doesn't FacePy send its own request via UrlEncode separately to the Facebook server? Thanks for your attention though.